# Customize environment "proof"

Tags: environments, theorems

I need to create (or customize) an environment "proof" that has the option to explain after the word 'proof' the name of the theorem (or environment) along with its automatic numbering of the theorem (or environment) to which proof relates.

Eg.

> Theorem 5.1 Blá blá blá Blá blá blá Blá blá blá Blá blá blá Blá blá
>   blá Blá blá blá  Blá blá blá Blá blá blá Blá blá blá Blá blá blá Blá
>   blá blá Blá blá blá  Blá blá blá Blá blá blá Blá blá blá Blá blá blá

Comments lá lá lá lá lá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lá

> Lema 5.2 Blá blá blá Blá blá blá Blá blá blá Blá blá blá Blá blá
>   blá Blá blá blá  Blá blá blá Blá blá blá Blá blá blá Blá blá blá Blá

Comments lá lá lá lá lá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá

> Lema 5.3 Blá blá blá Blá blá blá Blá blá blá Blá blá blá Blá blá
>   blá Blá blá blá  Blá blá blá Blá blá blá Blá blá blá Blá blá blá Blá

Comments lá lá lá lá lá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá lá lálá lá

> Proof of theorem 5.1. Blá blá blá Blá blá blá Blá blá blá Blá blá blá
>   Blá blá blá Blá blá blá Blá blá blá Blá blá blá Blá blá blá Blá blá
>   blá Blá blá blá Blá blá blá Blá blá blá Blá blá blá Blá blá blá Blá
>   blá blá Blá blá blá

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `amsthm` provides a `proof` environment that makes for an easy solution of your problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{maintheorem}
$1+1=2$.
\end{theorem}

We need a lemma.

\begin{lemma}
$2=1+1$.
\end{lemma}

This lemma, allows us to give an easy proof of the theorem.

\begin{proof}[Proof of theorem \ref{maintheorem}]
Use the commutative property.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```