# Name of the proof instead of just proof

Tags: theorems, optional-arguments

Packages I'm using:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}  
\usepackage{amsthm}  
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}  
\newtheorem{lma}{Lemma}  
\newtheorem{df}{Definition}  
 \newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}  
\theoremstyle{definition}  
 \newtheorem{exmp}{Example}[section]
```

I'm trying to prove a theorem and I have the following:

```
\begin{proof} (Proof of theorem)  
...  
\end{proof}
```

which outputs just "Proof. (Proof of theorem)".

Instead, I would like it to say "Proof of theorem." How can I do this? I tried

```
\begin{proof}[Proof of theorem \ref{maintheorem}]  
Use the commutative property.    
\end{proof}
```

which outputs "Proof of theorem??." But I don't want the question marks. How can I fix this?

Comment: It would be really great if you could supply us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your problem. There are many packages that provide theorem-like (and proof) environments, and answers may depend on which one you use.

Comment: Have I satisfied the MWE?

Comment: You probably didn't read the link I provided, since you've only given us the preamble and not a fully compilable (or working), minimal example. Either way, for now, the fact that it's visible you're using [`amsthm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) would probably suffice.

Comment: To answer your follow-up question: No, what you've posted is not an MWE, in part because you don't show which label you've given the theorem. Separately, did you run your program through LaTeX twice to let it resolve the cross-reference?

Comment: see also: [Customize environment “proof”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65144/579)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First thing you need is a `\label` in order to "mark" the theorem. That would give you the option of referencing the theorem using `\ref`. If you don't have a `\label` for some corresponding `\ref`, it will show up as **??** (see [Understanding how references and labels work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280/5764)).

Here's one setup that works in your case:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Some theorem]\label{thm:some-theorem}
This is an important theorem.

\begin{proof}
This is a very important proof.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}[Proof of Theorem~\ref{thm:some-theorem}]
This is a very important proof.
\end{proof}
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

I would consider the use-case above as the easiest. For example, one could make adjust the `proof` environment to handle its optional argument differently, but it may be overkill. Here's one such example that yields the same output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\relax]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep\itshape
    \ifx#1\relax \proofname\else\proofname{} of #1\fi\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Some theorem]\label{thm:some-theorem}
This is an important theorem.

\begin{proof}
This is a very important proof.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}[Theorem~\ref{thm:some-theorem}]
This is a very important proof.
\end{proof}
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

The above setup now takes the optional argument and prepends it with `Proof of`, assuming you'll only include some sort of reference.

Comment: Is it possible to get rid of the "1" in "Proof of Theorem 1."?

Comment: @EamesCobb: Hmmm... I thought that's what you wanted. In that case, just use `\begin{proof}[Proof of theorem]`...`\end{proof}`. Or, in the case of my updated `proof` environment, just use `\begin{proof}[theorem]`...`\end{proof}`.

Answer (score 2):

As `ntheorem` has an automatic handling of end-of-proof symbols, here is what one can do with it, and `cleveref`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{heuristica}

 \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thmmarks, amsmath, thref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries}
\theoremseparator{.}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{proof}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep\theorem@headerfont\MakeUppercase ##1\theorem@separator]}%
  {\item[\hskip \labelsep\theorem@headerfont\MakeUppercase ##1\ ##3\theorem@separator]}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{proof}
\theoremheaderfont{\scshape}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\square}}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Some theorem]\label{thm:some-theorem}
This is an important theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
This is a very important proof.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}[of \nameCref{thm:some-theorem}]
This is a very important proof.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}[of \Cref{thm:some-theorem}]
This is a very important proof.
\begin{align*}
    a & = b\\ c & = d.
\end{align*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]