# Problem with enumerate and margins

Tags: margins, enumerate

I have a problem with the automatic enumeration and thus I need some help. Specifically, adding the code

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries Πρόβλημα \arabic*.]


\item Αν $a,b,c$ είναι θετικοί πραγματικοί αριθμοί τότε να δείξετε ότι
$$\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b}\geq\frac{3}{2}.$$
\begin{flushright}
\textit{(Ανισότητα Nesbitt)}
\end{flushright}
\begin{center}
\textbf{\textit{Λύση.}}
\end{center}
Η προς απόδειξη ανισότητα είναι ισοδύναμη με την
$$\frac{2a}{b+c}+\frac{2b}{c+a}+\frac{2c}{a+b}\geq 3.$$
Προσθέτουμε το $3$ και στα 2 μέλη και τότε αρκεί να δείξουμε ότι
$$\frac{2a+b+c}{b+c}+\frac{2b+c+a}{c+a}+\frac{2c+a+b}{a+b}\geq 6,$$
ή ισοδύναμα
$$\frac{a+b}{b+c}+\frac{a+c}{b+c}+\frac{b+c}{c+a}+\frac{a+b}{c+a}+\frac{c+a}{a+b}+\frac{b+c}{a+b}\geq 6.$$
Αυτή η ανισότητα όμως ισχύει ήδη σύμφωνα με την ανισότητα \textit{AM-GM} αφού έχουμε
$$\sum\left(\frac{a+b}{b+c}+\frac{b+c}{a+b}\right)\geq 2+2+2=6.$$
Η ισότητα ισχύει όταν $a=b=c.$\hfill $\square$
```

looks like this

[image: latex sample]

My question is how can I have automatic enumeration but the solution I add under the problem is under the same margin with the "Πρόβλημα 1."?

Thanks,
George.

Comment: I think that you need a proof type environment.

Comment: Can you give me an example code of this, or a link to guide me through it?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/179821/14757 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34020/14757

Comment: Ah, I know this environment. But, maybe, I am not clear enough with my question. What I meant before, is my whole solution to be aligned under the letter "Π" from the enumerated "Πρόβλημα 1." and not aligned under the "." dot. How to achieve that?

Comment: a blank line after the centered element, followed by `\noindent`, should have the desired effect.  but i don't know whether this is logically appropriate.

Comment: Well, I think my problem is solved after seeing the key word \noindent. We need to add

    \noindent
       \begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries Πρόβλημα \arabic*,leftmargin=0cm,labelwidth=\itemindent,labelsep=0cm,align=left]

and thus we have the desired result.


Thank you for your time.

George.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the O.P. solved the problem himself.

Answer (score 1):

The OP George solved it this way, inserting `\noindent` as suggested by barbara, according to the comments:

```
\noindent
\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries Πρόβλημα \arabic*,
  leftmargin=0cm,labelwidth=\itemindent,labelsep=0cm,align=left]
```